Can't save CSV file from Excel (Windows 11, MS Office Home and Business 2019) to WSL 2 folder
I have an Excel file (MS Office Home and Business 2019, running under Windows 11) that I want to save as CSV file in a WSL folder underneath my WSL home folder. WSL is running as version 2 with Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS.
Trying to save as CSV results in the error message:
"Filename.xls" cannot be accessed. The file may be corrupted, located on a server that is not responding, or read-only.

Checking the folder shows that the file was created but has a length of 0 bytes.
I can access the folder (from Windows and WSL) without any problems. I also can save the file as native Excel file (.xlsx) and I don't get any errors, only when I try to save it as CSV.
Update
The path I use in Excel is
\\wsl$\Ubuntu-22.04\home\tim\projects\my-content\csv2json\some-file.csv

What path are you using exactly? [Edit] your question instead of submitting a temporary comment.

So I updated the question with the relevant information - do you have any idea? The problem still exists :-/ @Ramhound
